# Match json collection id to an array in the model and add corresponding as label

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I'm storing emotional data on my record model as json (I am encrypting the records table and don't want the potential of exposing data via relationships.):

**Record Migration**

```
Schema::create('records', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->text('title')->nullable();
    $table->json('emotions')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Here's the output I'm getting via my record resource:

**RecordResource**

```
class RecordResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'emotions' => $this->emotions
        ];
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
"data":[
   {
      "id":91,
      "title":"Temporibus sed ut voluptas nesciunt.",
      "emotions":[
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":1,
            "newIntensity":3
         },
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":2,
            "newIntensity":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":92,
      "title":"Facilis provident qui tempore sit illum fuga incidunt odio.",
      "emotions":[
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":1,
            "newIntensity":3
         },
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":2,
            "newIntensity":3
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What I want to do is store an emotions label either in the DB or for now just in an array in the records object:

```
class Record extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'emotions' => 'json',
    ];

    public $emtionsLabels = ['Happy', 'Sad'];
}
```

I then want to match the labels to the emotions collection and add an `is_picked` property so the output is like this:

**New Output**

```
"data":[
   {
      "id":91,
      "title":"Temporibus sed ut voluptas nesciunt.",
      "emotions":[
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":1,
            "newIntensity":3
            "label": "Happy",
            "is_picked": false
         },
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":2,
            "newIntensity":3
            "label": "Sad",
            "is_picked": false
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":92,
      "title":"Facilis provident qui tempore sit illum fuga incidunt odio.",
      "emotions":[
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":1,
            "newIntensity":3
            "label": "Happy",
            "is_picked": false
         },
         {
            "intensity":10,
            "emotion_id":2,
            "newIntensity":3
            "label": "Sad",
            "is_picked": false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I was going to try and give the emotions it's own resource `'emotions' => EmotionResource::collection(json_decode($this->emotions, true))`  so I could structure the json output there, but I'm getting a whole lot of problems:

> Trying to get property 'intensity' of non-object

```
class EmotionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return ['intensity' => $this->intensity];
    }
}
```

## Update 1

In my RecordController I've managed to get the output I want for emotions:

```
class RecordController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $emotions = Record::first()->emotions;

        $phpRecords = json_decode($emotions, true);

        $newEmotions;
        $record = new Record();
        $labels = $record->emtionsLabels;
        foreach($phpRecords as $emotion){
            $newEmotions[] = 
                [
                    'intensity' => $emotion['intensity'],
                    'new_intensity' => $emotion['newIntensity'],
                    'emotion_id'=> $emotion['emotion_id'],
                    'label' => $labels[$emotion['emotion_id'] - 1]
                ];
        }

        return collect($newEmotions);

    }
}
```

I just need to figure out how to do this in the EmotionResource or RecordResource.

Answer (score 0):

I created an accessor with the updated code above:

```
class Record extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /*protected $casts = [
        'emotions' => 'json',
    ];*/

    public $emtionsLabels = ['Happy', 'Sad'];

    public function getEmotionsAttribute($value)
    {
        $emotions = json_decode($value, true);
        foreach($emotions as $emotion){
            $newEmotions[] = 
                [
                    'intensity' => $emotion['intensity'],
                    'new_intensity' => $emotion['newIntensity'],
                    'emotion_id'=> $emotion['emotion_id'],
                    'label' => $this->emtionsLabels[$emotion['emotion_id'] - 1]
                ];
        }

        return collect($newEmotions); 
    }
}
```